# Checkstyle Unable to instantiate class

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle, gradle-submodule

I'm trying to build my project with gradle, which has submodule with checkstyle configured. Submodule building ends successfully. But running whole project gives error

```
Unable to instantiate 'com.company.CustomChecker' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as null. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
```

My `build.gradle` of submodule:

```
plugins {
   id 'checkstyle'
}
dependencies {
       checkstyle files('build/libs/submodule-project-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
checkstyle {
toolVersion = '8.11'
  config = rootProject.resources.text.fromFile('submodule-project-name/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
}
```

My `submodule-project-name/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml` which have `CustomChecker` using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="com.company.CustomChecker"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

but seems like when I build root module, it's kinda trying to find it in root module `src` which is not exists, not in submodule `src`. But when I run submodule `build.gradle` it works fine and is able to find the class.

Maybe I need to somehow configure checkstyle for root and configure that my `CustomChecker` path?

My checkstyle:

```
package com.company;

import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AbstractCheck;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.TokenTypes;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

public class CustomChecker extends AbstractCheck {


    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[]{TokenTypes.PACKAGE_DEF};
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getAcceptableTokens() {
        return new int[0];
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getRequiredTokens() {
        return new int[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST packageDef) {
    // impl of visit token
    }
// logic of my class

}
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Is `com.company.CustomChecker` the fully qualified class path (FQCP) of your module? Can you provide the class declaration and what it extends/implements? Checkstyle uses the classpath to find modules you specify using the FQCP. If it says it can't find it, besides an improperly configured Checkstyle class declaration, the other issue is it could not be found on the classpath. For example, you could have your class in an external JAR but forgot to add that JAR to the classpath.

Comment: @rveach, thanks, it's FQCP but this class is located under rootmodule/submodule/src/main/java/com/company/CustomChecker.java. And this class is included to submodule-1.0-snapshot.jar which is located under rootmodule/submodule/build/distributions/ folder and not in root project build folder

Comment: Your class does extend `AbstractCheck`, so that is good. Your FQCP of the class you provided is `com.company.checkstyle.TransformationsLoggingChecker` while the FQCP in the config is `com.company.CustomChecker`. I will have to take your word they are the same, but I would double check for any typos. It looks like the JAR isn't in your classpath, and unfortunately I don't know gradle and cannot help any further. It seems like this is a disconnect between Gradle and CS somewhere and the classpaths that are shared. If this works with CS' CLI, then it is a gradle issue.

Comment: You can checkout the gradle sample at https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/checkstyle-samples/blob/master/gradle-project/build.gradle#L45 and see if that helps you any.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and adding the project/module that contains the Checker class as a dependency to CheckStyle worked for me.

Example in Gradle Kotlin:

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "10.12.2"

    configFile = file("${rootDir}\\config\\checkstyle\\checkstyle.xml")
 
    // This part here - common is the module that contains my checker class (the one that extends AbstractCheck)
    dependencies {
        checkstyle("com.github.checkstyle:checkstyle:checkstyle-10.12.2")
        checkstyle(project(":common"))
    }
}
```